# Toggle button color VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, button, colors, toggle

I'm currently ussing the following code to change my buttons into orange once clicked but i would like to make it toggle between grey and orange so if clicked once it shows orange; if clicked again it shows grey and clicked again orange then grey orange then.... and so on

```
Private Sub F_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles F.Click
TextBox1.Text = 32
F.BackColor = Color.Orange
```

Answer (score 2):

```
F.BackColor = IIf(F.BackColor = Color.Orange, Color.Grey, Color.Orange)
```

Comment: You should the If operator instead of the IIf function, since it does proper short circuiting.

Comment: @Chris there is only one condition here so no need to worry about short circuiting.